# PHP get array items based on string mask

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array with a bunch of records like in:

```
{
   "ID": "38424",
   "heading": "Nylies soek nuwe hoof",
   "typeID": "1",
   "datein": "2016-09-26 12:14:16",
   "edited_datein": null,
   "publishDate": "2016-09-23 00:00:00",
   "category": {
       "ID": "1",
       "heading": "News",
       "typeID": "3",
       "datein": "2016-09-26 11:50:06",
       "edited_datein": null,
       "url": "news"
   },
   "authorID": "592",
   "tags": "skool,school,hoof,headmaster,etienne burger"
}
```

i have another array with "columns" i want the records to be "filtered" by

```
{
   "ID",
   "heading",
   "datein",
   "category|heading",
   "category|url"
}
```

i would like the result to create a multidimensional array based on the column items:

```
{
   "ID": "38424",
   "heading": "Nylies soek nuwe hoof",
   "datein": "2016-09-26 12:14:16",
   "category": {
       "heading": "News",
       "url": "news"
   }
}
```

how do i achieve this? i'm totally stuck on this now :( busy trying a hack of array_combine now but i dont hold much hope it would work out

Comment: isn't that a json string? unless its already decoded, and you're not showing us the full code, and shouldn't that columns supposed to be `[]` braces

Comment: i just turned the array to json for display purposes. i found a solution tho. posting it shortly

Comment: oh okay, sure, self answers are fine in SO

Answer (score 0):

so after being stuck on this for many hours.. and posting it here. i found a solution

```
$new_list = array();
foreach ($n as $record) {
    $new_list[] = filter_columns($columns, $record);
}
```

and the function:

```
function filter_columns($columns, $record, $pre="") {
    $return = array();
    foreach ($record as $key => $value) { // loop through the fields in the record
        $str = $pre.$key; // create a string of the current key
        if (in_array($str,$columns)){
            $return[$key] = $value; 
        }
        if (is_array($value)){
            $return[$key] = filter_columns($columns, $value,$key."|"); // if the value is an array recall the function but prepend the current key| to the key mask
        }


    }

    return $return;
}
```